# How to parse an M3U8 file in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, save, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to save .ts segments to the disk drive from an HLS stream to achieve record functionality. After going through [Record HTTP Live Streaming Video To File While Watching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671705/record-http-live-streaming-video-to-file-while-watching) and [Save HLS stream on iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171206/save-hls-stream-on-iphone-ipad) came to the conclusion to save the files to disk and set up a server locally and stream it from there. Bu I'm having issues parsing an M3U8 file. Found an [M3U8Kit](https://github.com/0day2010/M3U8Kit) but not what I was looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction as how to parse an M3U8 file? It looks something like this

```
#EXTM3U
```

`#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10`

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1

#EXTINF:10,
http://media.example.com/segment0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.example.com/segment1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.example.com/segment2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Please expand on why M3U8Kit is not what you're looking for. Is it due to licensing?

Comment: @vipw Nope, it converts the M3U8 file into plain NSString, but I'm looking for some regular expression parsers that can return the links or just the segment path component so that I can append and download them directly. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also for those who might need this, [M3U8Paser](https://github.com/Jeanvf/M3U8Paser) is an extended library of M3U8Kit to parse an m3u8 file to get the links for multiple m3u8 files used for adaptive streaming

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but the open source, MIT Licensed, [Pantomime](https://github.com/thomaschristensen/Pantomime) may serve your needs.